# React native render items inside Flatlist asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I'm looking to render items in my FlatList depending on the width and height of my pictures but getting those values takes a little bit of time, is it possible to turn this into an async function to wait for the response before rending the items?

I have tried adding the async/await keywords at different sport without success.

```
<FlatList
  ...
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return Image.getSize(item, (pictureWidth, pictureHeight) => {
      return(
              <Image
                source={{uri: item}}
                style={{
                  width: width,
                  height: parseInt(pictureHeight * (width / pictureWidth))
                }}/>
          )
```

Comment: Populate the list of Images. Using Promise.all() you can keep track of multiple async operations. When everything has finished loading, set a state variable like `loaded` to true. In your JSX, use conditional rendering: `{ this.state.loaded && FlatList ... /> }`

Comment: @ChrisG would love to see a more detailed snippet, I've been using react hooks, not very familiar with the Promise object.

Comment: How are you getting the image values? Are you using `<img>` and `onload`? Or do you have a list of images?

Comment: I'm using react native so I use the Image component, I've updated my question to include the code. @ChrisG

Comment: I see, here's how to promisify this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pm475vhr/ Instead of logging the outcome you'd put it in state, then render conditionally.